# Учитель военной прогимназии, коллежский регистратор Лев Пустяков

Tags: пунктуация, приложение

Это Чехов:

***Учитель военной прогимназии,*** **коллежский регистратор Лев Пустяков,** обитал рядом с другом своим, поручиком Леденцовым.

Это Розенталь:

***Учитель военной прогимназии, коллежский регистратор Лев Пустяков*** обитал рядом с другом своим, поручиком Леденцовым (Ч.) - связь между профессией-должностью и гражданским чином в дореволюционных учебных заведениях;

И вопросы:

1) **Куда пропала запятая** в правилах Розенталя?

2) **Объяснение однородности приложений** выглядит как-то неубедительно.

3) **Как можно объяснить** постановку запятых у Чехова?

Comment: Хм, написано, что между однородными приложениями ставится запятая, но **не написано**, что обособляется с двух сторон, а при этом в других примерах, кроме этого, обособлено именно с двух сторон (по ссылке на Розенталя из другого вопроса).

Comment: Как-то неудачно изложена тема, и запятой у Розенталя нет. А в ПАС под ред. Лопатина  одни доктора наук и мастера спорта, художественные тексты не разбираются. Может у Грамоты есть какая-нибудь информация?

Answer (score 1):

Неужели хоть один интересный вопрос, на который я самостоятельно отвечал)

Итак, давайте по порядку:

1. В первом случае, у Чехова, сочетание, содержащее собственное имя Лев Пустяков, является уточнением. В данном случае мы можем конкретизировать учителя, задав вопрос "кто именно этот учитель?" и дав на него исчерпывающий ответ, сразу заставляющий нас понять обсуждаемую личность. Например:

*Один из отличников в школе, Григорий Иванов, выиграл городскую олимпиаду.*

Здесь я специально включил слово "один" в главное слово, выполняющее роль подлежащего, чтобы показать, что, весьма вероятно, таких отличников в школе много (хотя, хочу отметить, уточнение не всегда требует такой ситуации. Можно заменить "один" на "единственный", в результате чего будет создано более детальное объяснение).
Подчеркну, что здесь идёт прямая зависимость роли сочетания от его места в предложении. Так, при перестановке данных частей первая, собственное имя, станет главным словом, от которого будет зависеть вторая, причём являющаяся приложением.

2. Во втором случае, у Розенталя, оборот "учитель военной прогимназии" является приложением, относящимся к собственному имени и имеющим ЗНАЧЕНИЕ ПРИЧИННОСТИ (выделите жирным, если не трудно). То есть мы можем выстроить следующую связь:

"Будучи учителем военной прогимназии, Лев Пустяков жил..." Зададим вопрос: "почему он там жил?" Ответ: потому что был учителем военной прогимназии. Чтобы было понятнее, перестрою предложение (да простит меня Чехов):

*Лев Пустяков жил со своим другом потому (делаю акцент на данном слове), что был учителем военной прогимназии.*

Надеюсь, понятно объяснил. Если что, спрашивайте в комментариях.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ,  но, к сожалению,  я смогу прокомментировать его только позже, сейчас нет возможности.

Comment: Хорошо, немного подожду

Comment: Вы правильно назвали два варианта (уточнение и причинное обособление), но у Розенталя другой вариант (третий) – однородные приложения. Кроме того, в этой теме  важно было понять смысловые оттенки, чтобы сделать наиболее подходящий выбор. В любом случае Вам удалось определить  дополнительный вариант, которого не было у Чехова и Розенталя (я его тоже не заметила). Поэтому еще раз благодарю Вас за участие в обсуждении.

Answer (score 0):

Для решения задачи надо определить возможные **грамматические варианты и их смысловое значение**.

**Вариант 1.**  *Учитель военной прогимназии, **коллежский регистратор Лев Пустяков,**  обитал рядом с другом своим, поручиком Леденцовым. Обособленное уточнение у Чехова.*

**Вариант 2.**  ***Учитель военной прогимназии, коллежский регистратор*** Лев Пустяков обитал рядом с другом своим, поручиком Леденцовым. Однородные приложения перед именем собственным (у Розенталя). Поэтому он и пытается объяснить их однородность, интонация перечислительная.

**Вариант 3.** ***Учитель военной прогимнАзии***, коллежский регистратор Лев Пустяков обитал рядом с другом своим, поручиком Леденцовым.

Первое приложение имеет значение причины и поэтому обособлено (вариант, предложенный в ответе). Этот вариант формально совпадает с вариантом  Розенталя, но читается совсем по-другому (двухчастная конструкция с подчеркнутой паузой).

Грамматически все варианты возможны, но смысловые оттенки в них разные, и, вероятно, Чехов выбрал  самый правильный.

**Смысловой анализ вариантов**

1) С этого предложения начинается рассказ «Орден». Определяемым словом является **учитель военной прогимназии**,  который живет рядом с другом-поручиком и просит у него орден на время. Именно **об учителе** хочет рассказать нам автор, поэтому имя и чин персонажа даются как уточнение.

2) Розенталь предлагает **однородные приложения** перед именем собственным. Но тогда **определяемым словом будет имя собственное Лев Пустяков,** которое выступает на первый план, а два приложения будут **однородными по значимости** (надо сказать, что другой однородности от этих приложений и не требуется).

Но автору было важно сразу назвать профессию героя, так как в рассказе фигурируют два учителя из этой гимназии. Поэтому он выбрал другой вариант (с уточнением).

3) **С одной стороны, есть что-то похожее:** прогимназия военная, друг его – поручик, вот они и живут рядом. **Но как-то странно звучит это причинное значение,** да еще в первом же предложении, когда автор представляет нам своего героя:  *Будучи учителем  военной прогимназии, коллежский регистратор Лев Пустяков обитал рядом с другом своим, поручиком Леденцовым.*

В конце концов, он мог жить и в другом месте, здесь нет жесткой обусловленности. Как мне кажется, этот вариант Чехов не одобрил бы.